# EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException in integration tests but not in application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bouncycastle, jasypt

I am using Jasypt with Bouncycastle in my Spring Boot application. I can run my application fine and encrypted stuff gets added in the database.

However, when running the unit tests, I get:

> org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine

Why does it work on my application and not the integration test (loads the same spring configuration as the application)? I am running both from IntelliJ IDEA using a standard Oracle Java 1.8.0_66.

I am using the `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC` algo.

Comment: Are use using Gradle? If yes, did Bouncycastle is configured for UT or just Runtime?

Comment: I am using Maven. But tests and application are both run from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java comes with a default maximum strength of 128 bits.

What you need is a set of files called **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files** and is currently available at the [Java SE download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). This zip file contains a couple of policy jars, which you need copy over the top of the ones already in the **{java.home}/jre/lib/security** directory of your JRE.

This will let you change the key strength above 128 bits

**UPDATE**

For Java 8, it will depend on the classpath. If one of the JCE jars (`local_policy.jar` or `US_export_policy.jar`) is present, then JCE unlimited cryptography is enabled. Maybe the Spring Boot application has this dependency fulfilled, but your tests not.

The JCE jars for Java 8 can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Comment: But why is it working on the application itself? Are you saying that it can never work without those files?

Comment: The process I described applies for Java 6, my bad. For Java 8, it will depend on the classpath. If one of the JCE jars (local_policy.jar or US_export_policy.jar) is present, then JCE unlimited cryptography is enabled. Maybe the Spring Boot applcation has this dependency fulfilled, but your tests not.  Those JARS can be found here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: Just found out that it also does not work on the (Ubuntu) server where I deploy to without those extra files. No idea why it seems to work on my Mac.

Comment: Note that more recent versions of Java 8 now have the policy jars built in.

Comment: I just had the same issue with Windows Server 2012. Java 8. Even though java came with both local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar, I still had to download new jars from Oracle and replace them.

Comment: @ Cristian Meneses With your input :
I have added local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar in class path but I am getting same error when without those jar in classpath.
FYI : I am using java version "1.7.0_80".